How to determine how much tax owed to dual citizen countries?
If one has dual citizenship and has capital gains, how does one determine how much they must pay to each country? How to do this correctly such that one doesn't underpay or overpay either side?

You would need to research both countries rules regarding recognition of foreign taxes, and look into potential tax treaties between the countries that may affect these rules. If you're a tax resident of both countries, then absent any explicit rule or treaty, you're by default taxed by both (aka double-taxed).
Many countries recognize this situation and provide for some relief either through bilateral treaties or through blanket rules providing for deductions or credits for foreign taxes paid (or both), but each country has its own rules on the matter. Without knowing the pair of countries in question and the circumstances it is impossible to answer more specifically.

Let's say the U.S. and Israel for a hypothetical example. And one earned 50k income all of it abroad but there was capital gains of 10k from selling stock held by a U.S. broker in case that matters.

You'll need to talk to an Israeli tax adviser. US taxes worldwide, Israel taxes its residents. US has a foreign tax credit, Israel has a bunch of different rules for recognition of foreign income depending on your legal status in the country (oleh, returning citizen, etc). Ah, and yes, there's a treaty.

Typically - Tax residence is separate from nationhood. You may live in a country and not be a citizen, yet still qualify for tax.
However, it's not unknown whether countries tax their citizens based on citizenship, i.e., The United States.
As far as I am aware, only two countries do this but you should really research this for yourself. Otherwise, it's probably just the country you're living in for 180 + days that matter.
Still INVESTIGATE your own case.

"Not unknown". It's just 3. US, Eritrea, Myanmar.

It's not just 180+ days, different countries have different rules. The US, for example, looks back for 3 years with a fairly complicated math to determine whether you're a resident or not. Other countries have "center of economic interests" tests that may be ambiguous.

"it's probably just" - I'm giving general advice to generalise 200 odd countries for one guy in a sentence. I think I did alright.
